# Word Search: two string arrays in alphabetical order using merge sort

Tags: java, dictionary, mergesort, wordsearch

For my class project, we have to go through the Shakespeare sonnet and check if each word is in the dictionary or not. Now I have two String arrays both in alphabetical order, one consists of the words from the sonnet and the other one is consisted of the word from the dictionary. I am asked to use the merge sort to check if the word in the sonnet exists in the dictionary. Can anyone give me an idea of how I can implement this??? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it how to approach the problem, or is it the mergesort itself, that puzzles you?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to:

1. Sort both of the arrays (with merge sort)
2. Remove any duplicates
3. Iterate through both of the sorted arrays simultaneously (can be done using the merging procedure in mergesort) and check if the next word in the sonnet list equals the next word in the dictionary. If it does not, remove it, and mark it as "not in dictionary", if it is, mark it as "in the dictionary", and proceed to the next element in both lists

However, this approach assumes that all of the words in the dictionary is contained in the sonnet. If this is not the case, you would have to remove those words up front.

Really though; this doesn't sound like a sort problem. 
The best approach would be to use a `HashMap` and put all the dictionary words in that. Then you could iterate through the sonnet, and check for existence in the map.